# Referring to a cell value in Name Manager of Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the name manager, I want a range formula to refer to a cell which I can change the value of.

I have the following formula as a defined name in Name Manager

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$KO$3:$NH$3,0,1,1,NumRows)
```

I want the 3 in the above to refer to cell "A1", the intention is that I can enter a number into cell "A1" for example 12 so that the defined name will then change to

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$KO$12:$NH$12,0,1,1,NumRows)
```

I have a graph that is linked to the formula above so that when I change the cell value in cell "A1" my graph will then find the corresponding row in my data matrix and update accordingly.

Can someone assist, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet2!$KO$3:$NH$" & A1),0,1,1,NumRows)
```

Comment: Thanks this works great i needed to adjust the the first three to & A1 though

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$KO$1:$NH$1, Sheet2!$A$1-1, 1, 1, NumRows)
```

... or discard OFFSET altogether.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$KO:$KO, Sheet2!$A$1):INDEX(Sheet2!$KO:$NH, Sheet2!$A$1, NumRows)
```

TBH, I find your use of NumRows confusing since it refers to the number of columns in your original OFFSET.